# Question on the number of samples in LSTM

Tags: python, keras, cross-validation, lstm-stateful

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
def build_model():

  model2=Sequential()
  model2.add(LSTM(8,batch_input_shape=(12,12,1),stateful=True))
  model2.add(Dense(8))
  model2.add(Dense(8))
  model2.add(Dense(1))
  model2.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam')
  return model2
model=KerasRegressor(build_fn=build_model, epochs=50, batch_size=12, verbose=0)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=np.random.seed(7))
score=cross_val_score(model,ts_x,ts_y,cv=kfold,scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
```

ts_x.shape is (228,12,1)
ts_y.shape is (228,1,1)
As we can see here, I have 228 samples now,but when I run it:
`ValueError: In a stateful network, you should only pass inputs with a number of samples that can be divided by the batch size. Found: 183 samples.`
I want to know why it founded 183 samples instead 228 samples?

Answer (score 0):

**What the error means:**
The batch_size you have provided is `12`, that is, `12` records are taken for the training process every time. Now, your total records are `228`, which isn't a multiple of `12`, so the last batch doesn't have enough records to train.
However, that is not where the problem is. You are also using 5 fold cross-validation. That means your dataset is divided into 5 parts, out of which 1 part is kept untouched as a validation set whereas the model trains on the other 4 parts. The length of these parts is `228/5 = 45.6` and `228*4/5 = 182.4 (~ 183)`. 
So, the model training which occurs is actually on `183` records at a time, which is again, not a multiple of `12`.

**Potential solution:** 
You can try setting the `batch_size` to a factor of 183 (1,3,61,183) which doesn't give you much reasonable options. 
So, you can try changing your `n_splits` to something close (like 6), so that `228 * (n_splits  - 1)/n_splits` has factors close to 10 (if `n_splits` is `6`, `10` is one of the possible `batch_size`s)

Apart from that, I am sorry I don't have experience with tensorflow since I use pytorch, and pytorch doesn't show an error even if the last batch isn't a *full* batch. Still, you could look at tensorflow's documentation and their own q/a forums to get another answer.

I hope this solves your problem or at least guides you in the right direction towards a solution.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your solution. It is useful for me, but another error happens when I follow your suggestion, setting the batch_size=10,n_splits=6:
InvalidArgumentError: data[0].shape = [3] does not start with indices[0].shape = [2]
  [[{{nodeAdam_21/gradients/loss_21/dense_65_loss/Mean_grad/DynamicStitch}}]]
Could you help me more? Thank you very much!

Comment: @chee sorry for the late reply but this has to do with your dataset, since I don't know keras, I can only guide you: [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56604825/keras-invalidargumenterror-with-model-fit) [link 2](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/issues/327)